# Wanted autocomplete in input field but not getting it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to get some university name from database with get method. I got data but when I try from input field, I am not getting it and there's no dropdown. I didn't get where the problem is.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    // CSRF Token
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $( "#universityName" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
          // Fetch data
          $.ajax({
            url:"{{route('university.universityName')}}",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
               _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
               search: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
               response( data );
            }
          });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
           // Set selection
           $('#universityName').val(ui.item.value); // display the selected text
           /*$('#employeeid').val(ui.item.value);*/ // save selected id to input
           return false;
        }
      });

    });
    </script>
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control w-100" name="universityName" id="universityName" placeholder="Search by University Name">
```

```
public function getUniversityName(Request $request){
  $search = $request->search;

  if($search == ''){
     $universityname = DB::table('universities')->orderby('universityname','asc')->select('universityname')->limit(5)->get();
  }else{
     $universityname = DB::table('universities')->orderby('universityname','asc')->select('universityname')->where('universityname', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')->limit(5)->get();
  }

  $response = array();
  foreach($universityname as $universityname){
     $response[] = array("value"=>$universityname->universityname);
  }

  return response()->json($response);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add autocomplete="universityName" to your input field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control w-100" name="universityName" id="universityName" placeholder="Search by University Name" autocomplete="universityName">
```